# Как защитить сервер Linux от копирования?

Tags: php, linux

Имеется PC с установленной Linux CentOS 8. На нем развернут LAMP с коммерческим проектом на PHP. PC будет позднее установлен на территории клиента и будет приносить клиенту деньги. Тонкости - проект может работать без интернета, на локальной сети.

Задача: сделать так, чтобы проект был недоступен для клиента, он не мог его скопировать или запустить вторую копию этого проекта на другом объекте. Сам проект работает как web-сервер, вход пользователя ему не нужен. Схема - включил PC и все работает.

Какие варианты были уже рассмотрены:

1. Вариант проверки в коде серийного номера SSD. Ломается легко - вынимается SSD, открывается на другом PC, находится проект на PHP, находится проверка серийного номера, удаляется, проект работает на любом SSD.
2. Защита на уровне ОС, пользователь с неизвестным клиенту паролем. Ломается выниманием SSD из PC и запуском на другом PC, далее SSD открывается на чтение, разбирается код на PHP и делается копия проекта
3. Шифрование диска на уровне ОС. Для работы нужно ввести пароль, без пароля ОС не запускается. Решение тупиковое - клиенту нельзя давать пароль, а без пароля ничего не работает. Если дать пароль - то все пропало.
4. Обфусцирование/шифрование кода. Ничего не дает, проект работает на одном PC, клиент просто делает копию и получает второй работающий проект с зашифрованным и обфусцированным кодом. Обфусцирование и шифрование части кода с проверкой лиценции также ничего не дает, отлично находится и исключается.

В итоге упорно ищу способ сделать PC с SSD, который работает только в такой конфигурации, и никак иначе. Даже думали над установкой аппаратных пломб или ключей на USB, но снятие SSD и копирование/разбор информации на нем ставят крест на любых проверках.

Буду очень благодарен за указание на готовое решение, или за любые мысли о том, как это можно сделать.

Comment: Посылать логи к вам SN оборудования привязок. Все зашифровать.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик ) К сожалению, даже если мы узнаем о дополнительной копии, которую запустил клиент, сделать ничего не сможем с этим. Клиент очень далеко, в другом полушарии. Задача как раз не допустить копии, или сделать ее изготовление дороже чем купить у нас еще одну

Comment: В пункте 4 вы не правы. Шифрованный поддерживает прикрепление к ip/dns адресу машины, на которой он работает. Посмотрите на ionCube, например

Comment: А банальные юридические меры? Договор и штрафы?

Comment: Раз вы так друг другу не доверяете, остается полная предоплата ulimited версии

Comment: [saas](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0)

Comment: Привязку к серийнику диска подписать эцп. Некоторую критичную часть кода закомпилить в обфусцированный файл и там же сделать проверку подписи

Comment: IP локальный, в локальной сети. Юридические нормы идея хорошая, но нужны юристы, у нас их пока нет. SAAS не подойдет - там нет интернета, или есть, но редко, работает в локальной сети это дело. Да, пока самое хорошее что придумалось - это шифрование критической части кода ключем, привязанным к аппаратной платформе. А ключ расшифровки этой части кода положить на USB токен.

Comment: Ну вы извращенцы, конечно xD

Comment: я про подпись говорил - там можно без токена обойтись) ну токен тоже варик))

Comment: Используйте ionCube - там есть большинство фич, необходимых вам (привязка к железу И обфускация, и др)

Comment: Если ставите "коробочку", то все можно решить своей сборкой ядра, привязанной к конкретным MAC адресам адаптеров и зашифрованными на них файлами в SSD

Comment: Если найдете решение сообщите Microsoft чтоб закрыли клонирование на любые носители или виртуалки

Answer (score 1):

Если есть доступ к диску, то практически никак. Тем более для php. Диск можно склонировать, из php кода (даже обфусцированного) можно вырезать проверку. Единственное что можно попробовать сделать - взять исходники модуля работы с выбранной БД ([например](https://github.com/php/pecl-database-mysql)), встроить туда проверку идентификатора машины и, собственно, захардкодить туда предварительно сгенерированный идентификатор. Ну и вызывать проверку при подключении к БД. Соответственно, поставлять модуль вместе с сайтом. Ну и поддерживать его придётся тоже, да.